# Jittery and Jumpy camera movement with SDL2 and OpenGL

Tags: opengl, sdl2, c, glew

i have successfully been able to draw a cube using openGL and SDL2. To me the next natural step would be to add some basic forward/backward movement to the camera. I did so with this code here:

```c
    // SDL Window init and GLSL setup ^^

    vec3 cameraPos = {0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f};
    vec3 cameraTarget = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    vec3 cameraFront = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};


    while(!quit){

        vec3 cameraDirection;

        glm_vec3_sub(cameraTarget, cameraPos, cameraDirection);
        glm_normalize(cameraDirection);

        vec3 up = {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
        vec3 cameraRight;

        glm_cross(cameraDirection, up, cameraRight);
        glm_normalize(cameraRight);

        vec3 cameraUp;

        glm_cross(cameraRight, cameraDirection, cameraUp);

        vec3 cameraFrontPlusPos;
        glm_vec3_add(cameraFront, cameraPos, cameraFrontPlusPos);

        float cameraSpeed = 0.05f;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_w:
                        {
                            vec3 scaledFront;
                            glm_vec3_scale(cameraFront, cameraSpeed, scaledFront);
                            glm_vec3_add(cameraPos, scaledFront, cameraPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case SDLK_s:
                        {
                            vec3 scaledFront;
                            glm_vec3_scale(cameraFront, cameraSpeed, scaledFront);
                            glm_vec3_sub(cameraPos, scaledFront, cameraPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case SDLK_a:
                        {
                            vec3 right;
                            glm_vec3_cross(cameraFront, cameraUp, right);
                            glm_normalize(right);
                            glm_vec3_scale(right, cameraSpeed, right);
                            glm_vec3_sub(cameraPos, right, cameraPos);
                        }
                        break;
                    case SDLK_d:
                        {
                            vec3 right;
                            glm_vec3_cross(cameraFront, cameraUp, right);
                            glm_normalize(right);
                            glm_vec3_scale(right, cameraSpeed, right);
                            glm_vec3_add(cameraPos, right, cameraPos);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Cube Rendering code down here

    }
```

because i am writing this in c i am not using glm but i am using cglm that is provided by this github page: https://github.com/recp/cglm.

The problem that i am having is that when i move left and right the camera seems to be jumpy and not smooth like when i move forward and backwards.

I have tried introducing a deltaTime variable that gets multiplied to my cameraSpeed, but that did not seem to have done anything. I then tried adding a delay to the game loop by using SDL_Delay(10) and that made the jittery thing worse. I also tried changing the Swap interval from 0 to 1 to -1 and 0 was the smoothest and 1 and -1 where really jittery.